# Different formats but using same IEEETran template

Tags: ieeetran

I'm using the IEEETran.cls (version 1.7) file to compile my latex files. The sample pdf from the website shows the title format in image (1). However it is showing as image (2) in my system. I'm not modifying the template and using the same *.tex file.
Same is the issue with entries in references. In the first method, there is spacing between entries and in the latter they is no spacing at all.

Are these both acceptable formats for IEEE conferences. If not how do I get the actual formatting.

Thanks,
kris

[image]

[image]

Comment: the top one is created via `ieeeconf`. You can download it often from the conference website in the author kit. IEEEtran conference mode is not used that much anymore.

Comment: IEEE Computer Society has slightly different formatting requirements than most other IEEE conferences; the `ieeeconf.cls` class tailors to those requirements, whereas `ieeetran.cls` with `conference` option is more appropriate for most other societies' conferences.